# Legacy PHP codebase issue cropped up recently with Login/Logout

Tags: php, session, authentication

Someone I did some work for last year has advised me his login/logout system isn't working. The problem is I haven't touched the login system.

The code is old as sin, php 5.2 I believe, I've looked into it, when using the inspector tool, disabling caching allows me to logout successfully. If it isn't the system refuses to log me out and just reloads the current page. Now I didn't build this login/logout code and its messy. I'm looking at potentially using Session Destroy before the cookies are set to an empty string?

Before I do anything radical, can anyone with a strong php background decipher whats happening and suggest if using $session_destroy() at the start of the logout php file is the correct action?

I know chrome underwent a large update end of last year, is it possible this has affected the code? (being so old)

Heres the logout code.

```
# cookie stuff
setcookie("user", "", time() - 3600,"/");
setcookie("userid","", time() - 3600,"/");
setcookie("usertype","", time() - 3600,"/");

header("Location: index.php");
```

The login

```
# set session time to 60 mins
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime",3660);

session_start();

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

# connect to the database
include "includes/mysql.php";

** Removed database stuff.

if ($data != "") {

    # set session data
    #if ($data->nick) $HTTP_SESSION_VARS['user']=$data->nick;
    #if (!$data->nick) $HTTP_SESSION_VARS['user']=$data->name;
    #$HTTP_SESSION_VARS['userid']=$data->recid;
    #$HTTP_SESSION_VARS['usertype']=$data->usertype;

    # set cookie with expiry in 7 days
    $expiry = time()+60*60*24*7;

    if ($data->nick) setcookie("user",$data->nick,$expiry,"/");
    if (!$data->nick) setcookie("user",$data->name,$expiry,"/");
    setcookie("userid",$data->recid,$expiry,"/");
    setcookie("usertype",$data->usertype,$expiry,"/");
    setcookie("usershopid",$data->resellerid,$expiry,"/");

    header("Location: index.php");
}
else {
    header("Location: login.php?error=invalid");
}  
}
?>
```

The Header

```
<?php
# set this to work around register_globals
import_request_variables("pg");

# set session time to 60 mins
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime",28800);

# initiate session
session_start();

# connect to database
include "includes/mysql.php";
include "includes/functions.php";
include "includes/GST.class.php";
$objGST = new GST();

if (!isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
    header("Location: ".$dir."login.php");
}

# set cache options
session_cache_limiter('private');
header("Cache-control: private"); // IE 6 Fix. 

$user = $_COOKIE["user"];
$userid = $_COOKIE['userid'];
$usertype = $_COOKIE['usertype'];
$usershopid = $_COOKIE['usershopid'];

?>
```

Index.php

```
<?php
include $dir."includes/header.php";
include $dir."includes/mysql.php";
?>
<?php
```

Comment: So you are using cookies not sessions correct? I can't imagine `session_destroy();` will do anything if you are not using sessions (`$_SESSION`).

Comment: *"if using `$session_destroy()` at the start of the logout php file is the correct action?"* - Minus the `$` sign; and yes, you destroy the session on logout if sessions are used, if not then unset the cookie. What version of php/mysql is running on the server?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I believe its PHP 5.2. The weird thing is as you can see the login uses cookies, but each page has a session as well, the logout seems to be unsetting cookies to a "" string.

Comment: `$HTTP_SESSION_VARS` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php is deprecated. If the server doesn't support it, use `$_SESSION` http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php again; the version of php may be the problem if it was upgraded. If you're using `mysql_*` functions, and the server's like 7, then you can't use those. `mysql_` was deprecated as of 5.5 http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php See if anything comes of error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I also see quite a few commented out lines `#` related to sessions. Those won't take effect at all. Did you comment those out or was it already like that? I.e.: `#if ($data->nick) $HTTP_SESSION_VARS['user']=$data->nick;` and others below that. You should also add `exit;` after every header.

Comment: The comments were all like that, I had to downgrade the area of the site I made to work on his server, but the stuff I did was independent of this system. I didn't add any comments, I made some brief changes to the index page adding some sql, I wonder if I removed a SESSION_START or something of the like.

Comment: When I disable caching the logout works fine.

Comment: Side note, maybe a bigger issue than login being broken, but it looks like there's no mechanism to prevent a user from just modifying their cookies and being logged in as a different user.  Is that the case?  And yeah, it looks like all the session stuff is unnecessary as the login state is in the cookies, not a session.

Comment: Looking at how to unset cookies, it seems the current code should work? Unless it cannot access them from the index.php? I have advised him that the site is fairly insecure, he doesn't seem to care.

Comment: Easy enough to see using the network console if the cookies are persisting through a logout.  Blunt force solution might just be adding a header `Cache-control: no-cache` to disable browser caching of pertinent pages.

Comment: They are persistent, where should I add the no-cache header?

Comment: Header.php looks good, next to the other cache-control directive.